# How to process a .png or .jpg file in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I started my zookeper and kafkaServer and able to send messages from producer to consumers
But i couldn't figure how to process a image and send it from producer to consumer?

**zookeeper**

```
./bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

kafkaServer

```
./bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

**Created a Topic**

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --
replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic img_process
```

Answer (score 1):

When you store a message into Kafka you really just store an array of bytes, so yes you can pass the image via Kafka,  Just read the image as one big byte array and send via a producer.  You may want to store additional metadata in the key or header.

Having said that, you will be getting some rather large messages.  Another approach is to store the image on a file system somewhere (a distributed file system if producer and consumer will be on different machines) and sent the URI (absolute file name) as the content of the message.  This has the benefit of being much more efficient as far as Kafka is concerned, but you now have to deal with maintaining data in two different places.  Also, note that there is sometimes a lag time with distributed file systems and the Kafka message containing the file's URI could be available to the consumer before the file itself is available to the consumer.

Comment: So how do I proceed? If I need this working on a large scale with lots of images?